# Multi-dimentional packed parameter declaration using function

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Recently I am thinking pre-calculating all necessary parameters using simple mathematical equations before instantiating logic units in generate struct. In the case where I need to have a 2-D parameter, it's easy if the 2-D array is a set of fixed values, such as

`parameter para_1[1:0][2:0] = '{2{3{0}}};`.

But what I want is a function that dictates the values, such that complicated equations can be implemented inside the function before assigning the return values to the parameter.

Ideally I want something as follows:

```
function func01 [1:0][1:0] (input int test);
  int index;
  for (index=0; index<=2; index++) begin
    func01[index] = index + $floor(index/2) + $mod(index, 2) + test;
  end
endfunction

parameter test1 = 1;
parameter logic test2 [1:0][1:0] = func01(test1);
```

But ModelSim complains about the first line of code straightaway - `** Error: (vlog-13069) near "[": syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ';' or '('.`

Ultimately the idea is to have a block that calculates all parameters/constants at elaboration time, so that these can be used in generate block for instantiation, also at elaboration time.

Hope it makes sense, and thanks a lot in advance.

Best,
Taihai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you want packed arrays, the dimension ranges goes to the left of the array name. And I suggest using an explicit data type.

```
parameter bit [1:0][2:0] para_1 = '{2{3{0}}};.
```

Then, the return type of function declaration comes before the function name.

```
function bit [1:0][1:0] func01  (input int test);
```

BTW if you want the return type of a function to have an unpacked dimension, you must use a `typedef`, which is a good practice in any case.

```
typedef bit [1:0] myParam_t [2:0];
parameter myParam_t para_1 = '{default:0};
function myParam_t func01  (input int test);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this @dave_59. The title and the content was meant to do with unpacked arrays, not packed. Sorry. And your solution seems to be what I am after on the `typedef` side. However, ModelSim doesn't like system function (e.g. $floor) in function block `System functions may not be used in a constant function.`. Is there any get-around?

Comment: You will need to use the SystemVerilog equivalent operator (`%` for mod) or write a replacement equation (`let floor(val) = int'(val) > val ? int'(val) -1 : int'(val);` for floor)